# Can I change a GCE VM instance type on the fly?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm working with Google Compute Engine and to test it I created a small instance type which isn't very powerful. Now I want to change it to a more powerful CPU but can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Is it possible to change the instance type of a running VM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't change the instance type of a running instance, so you'll have to **shut it down and start a new one**.

If you used a persistent root disk, you can reuse that disk on your replacement instance. If you used a scratch disk though, you'll have to make sure you back up your changes first.

Comment: Scratch disk doesn't exist anymore so that shouldn't be an issue any longer.

Answer (score 3):

In December 2013, Compute Engine was promoted to v1 (General Availability).  Some notes to hopefully save folks time:

- Scratch disks are deprecated.  By default boot disks are now created as persistent.
- Before you delete the old instance, save off its settings for easy reference when creating the new one:

  ```
  gcutil getinstance instance-name
  ```
- The disk name to use later for `addinstance` is the last part of the `disk.source` setting.
- If the `disk.autoDelete` setting is `True`, set it to `False` to preserve the disk:

  ```
  gcutil setinstancediskautodelete instance-name --auto_delete=False
  ```
- Safely delete the old instance:

  ```
  gcutil deleteinstance instance-name
  ```
- To create a new instance using the old instance's persistent disk as the boot disk, you need to specify the `boot` flag, e.g. using `gcutil`:

  ```
  gcutil addinstance --disk=instance-disk-name,mode=rw,boot [...]
  ```

  Otherwise it complains that the disk already exists and fails the instance creation.